# How to disable an UITableViewCell custom animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a custom animation for my table view done inside `willDisplay` delegate.
I want this animation to be disabled in one case, but I don't know how to do this.

I tried doing this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
```

But the animation is still performed. Any other way to disable animations on IOS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it yourself

```
var enabled  = true

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      if enabled {
         // do animation
      }
      else {

      }

   }
```

Comment: I can't do that, because I want this animation to be performed when the vc is presented. After is presented I want to prevent it (when I click some items from table view reloadData() is called)

Comment: Added another check to see when vc is presented and when item is selected. Working now.

Comment: Great , keep innovating